# Zend Framework 2 - Using Memcache/Memcached to store DB results

Tags: php, zend-framework2, memcached

I tried to implement memcache to store Db results (within tablegateway), but I have a problem. Without "setItem" and "getItem" methods, the query works fine, but if I use them, it displays this error:

```
An error occurred

An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
PDOException
File:
C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\ZF-Tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Serializer\Adapter\PhpSerialize.php:48
Message:
You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement instances
```

Inside my tablegateway there is a

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Application\Model\Defaultlanguage;

class AccessoriesTable 
{
    protected $tableGateway;
    protected $cache;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}


public function setCache(StorageInterface $cache)
{
    $this->cache = $cache;
} 


public function fetchAll($lang = null)
{
    if(!isset($lang))  {  
        $lang = DefaultLanguage::LANG;
    }

    if( ($result = $this->cache->getItem('testcache')) == FALSE) {
        $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
        $sql = new Sql($adapter);
        $select = $sql->select();
        $select->columns(array(
            'id',
            'accessories' => $lang
        ));
        $select->from('cat_accessories'); 
        $select->order('accessories ASC');
        $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $statement->execute();

        $this->cache->setItem('testcache',  $result);
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

inside my module.php

```
'Application\Model\AccessoriesTable' =>  function($sm) {
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('AccessoriesTableGateway');
    $cacheAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Cache\Storage\Memcache');
    $table = new AccessoriesTable($tableGateway);
    $table->setCache($cacheAdapter);
    return $table;
},
'AccessoriesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Accessories());
    return new TableGateway('cat_accessories', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```

I tried to use memcache inside my controller and view and works fine. I don't understood where is(are) the error(s). Thanks you all for the help.

**EDIT 28-06-2015**

I found a solution here, works fine but I don't like so much:
https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/zend-framework-2-using-zendcache-and-hydratingresultset-to-save-database-resultset/

inside module.php

```
'Application\Model\AccessoriesTable' =>  function($sm) {
    $dbAdapter    = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $cacheAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Cache\Storage\Memcache');
    $table = new AccessoriesTable($dbAdapter);
    $table->setCache($cacheAdapter);
    return $table;
},
```

Inside Accessories Class:

```
namespace Application\Model;

class Accessories 
{
    public $id;
    public $accessories;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->accessories     = (!empty($data['accessories'])) ? $data['accessories'] : null;
    }   

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

Inside AccessoriesTable:

```
namespace Application\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Application\Model\Accessories;
use Application\Model\Defaultlanguage;

class AccessoriesTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'cat_accessories';
    protected $cache;
    public $lang;

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setObjectPrototype(new Accessories());
        $this->initialize();
    }

    public function fetchAll($lang = null)
    {
        $this->setLang($lang);
        $cacheName = md5('accessories-'.$this->lang);
        if( ($resultSet = $this->cache->getItem($cacheName)) == FALSE) {
            $resultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select){
                $select->columns(array('id', 'accessories'=> $this->lang ));
                $select->order(array($this->lang. ' asc'));  
            });
            $this->cache->setItem($cacheName ,  $resultSet );
        }
        return $resultSet; 
    }
}
```

**NEW QUESTION** : how can I implement it with "traditional" tablegateway construct????

I tried to use traditional tablegateway but the error is the same above.

inside tablegateway:

```
public function fetchAll($lang = null)
{
    $this->setLang($lang);
    $cacheName = md5('accessories-'.$this->lang);
    if( ($resultSet = $this->cache->getItem($cacheName)) == FALSE) {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select){
            $select->columns(array('id', 'accessories'=> $this->lang ));
            $select->order(array($this->lang. ' asc'));  
        });
        $this->cache->setItem($cacheName ,  $resultSet );
    }
    return $resultSet; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the errors:

```
$result = $statement->execute();
$this->cache->setItem('testcache',  $result);
```

Your $result variable is an ResultSet object, which you are trying to insert inside memcached (the whole object, not it's return data only). Try doing this `$result->current();` and let me know what happened.

**EDIT: 28.06.2015**

Since the link I gave you will expires after a week, I decided to include the code in

```
/**
 * Create plain mysql queries.
 *
 * @param String $sql the plain query
 * @throws Exception If database is not found or $sql is empty
 * @return array|HydratingResultSet|null
 */
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result;

public static function createPlainQuery($sql = null)
{
    $dir = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));

    if (!is_file($dir.'/config/autoload/local.php')) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not load database settings");
    }

    if (empty($sql)) {
        throw new \Exception(__METHOD__ . ' must not be empty');
    }

    $local = require($dir.'/config/autoload/local.php');
    $db = new Adapter($local['db']);
    $stmt = $db->createStatement((string) $sql);
    $stmt->prepare();
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if ($result instanceof Result && $result->isQueryResult() && $result->getAffectedRows()) {
        $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet(new ObjectProperty(), new \stdClass());
        $resultSet->initialize($result);
        $resultSet->buffer();

        return ($resultSet->valid() && $resultSet->count() > 0 ? $resultSet->toArray() : null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Works! but current() returns only a row of the query results.

Comment: Ok, so. Try calling $result->toArray(), but my guess is that it's going to throw an exception. The other way is just to iterate over this with a `foreach loop. foreach($result as $key => $res) { $this->cache->setItem('testcache', $res); }`
Also, this is my own implementation of a plain mysql query function. WIth this function you will get a plain array result  (just an array, not an arrayobject or anything else), which you can directly insert in your memcache
http://paste.ofcode.org/ujWdDnkm6FmQ5b6GHBQYJB

Comment: look the new edit, I found a solution but I don't like so much

Answer (score 0):

The main problem which clearly noted in first error message; you're trying to saving a `PDOStatement` instance which is the output of the `execute()` method. Then your caching backend is automatically trying to serialize that statement instance which actually is not serializable.

```
$result = $statement->execute();
$this->cache->setItem('testcache',  $result);
```

Just get the data from resultset and iterate over it. Convert the data into an array while iterating or if the items are objects then add an `getArrayCopy()` method to this objects by implementing [ArraySerializableInterface](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html) to easily extract an array copy of the object and store into the cache.

Returning a simple associative array in `getArrayCopy()` method will be enough for most scenarios, for example:

```
public function getArrayCopy()
{
   return [
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
       'bar' => $this->bar,
       'baz' => $this->baz,
   ];
}
```

Comment: I've a getArrayCopy method inside Accessories class. Look the new edit, I found a solution here: https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/zend-framework-2-using-zendcache-and-hydratingresultset-to-save-database-resultset/

but I don't like the table construct. How can I implement with the "traditional" tablegateway construct?